# <client-only> in Nuxt makes content disappear when running generate

Tags: static, nuxt.js

Does someone know why this happens? If I run nuxt locally (server) it works fine, but whenever I run `yarn generate` and load the index.html file in my browser all content between `<client-only>` tags disappear.

My nuxt config file:

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: true,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'Site name',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'nl'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Description
    ],

    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'preconnect', href: "https://fonts.gstatic.com"},
      { href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@700&display=swap', rel: 'stylesheet'}
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: ["@/assets/css/hamburgers.scss"],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/tailwindcss
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
    '@nuxtjs/fontawesome',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
  ],

  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      "assets/css/variables.scss",
      "assets/css/hamburgers.scss",
    ]
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Comment: The code of `index.html` would be useful here IMO. Also, a [repro] could heavily help I think.

Comment: Can you host a [repro] on codesandbox or Github?

Comment: @kissu Isn't needed anymore, the solution for it was really simple. The client-only didn't work because javascript was broken because the paths to the files didn't work in the index.html when accessing the file from a folder on my pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've got it to work.

Javascript wasn't working properly because the files weren't linked correctly when I open index.html.

Because index.html is in a local folder somewhere on my PC, it searches for the javascript files on the root of the machine (where they don't exist).

I tested this locally on an Apache server with XAMPP and the same problem ocurred when I put the `dist` content generated by `yarn generate` in a subfolder so the URL would be `localhost/subfolder`.

The fix for this specific problem in this context would be to add to `nuxt.config.js` this:

```
router: {
  base: '/subfolder/'
},
```

In the end this solution was not neccesary for me because when I were to host this on an actual Apache server and would put the files in the root directory so then the `router` property isn't needed unless I would put it there in a subfolder.

---

Earlier related questions from me:

[Click events in Nuxt don't work after generating static site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67325522/click-events-in-nuxt-dont-work-after-generating-static-site/67356304#67356304)

[Href and src generated by Nuxt in static site are not properly linked to js files after nuxt generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479200/href-and-src-generated-by-nuxt-in-static-site-are-not-properly-linked-to-js-file)

Comment: You usually should run your server with a webpack server in dev or prod, not opening your file directly. As with Rails.