# Click events in Nuxt don't work after generating static site

Tags: static, nuxt.js

I have a simple hamburger menu button which appears when after clicking a button with `v-on:click="$store.dispatch('toggleMobileMenu')"`. This all works fine when running locally or non-static. However when I use `yarn generate` the click event doesn't seem to work anymore.

Anyone else having the same issues or know a possible solution to this?

Comment: We will need a [repro] here to help you. Is your JavaScript enabled btw?

Comment: I have the same issue, been banging my head against this for days now. Trying to get a working generated site with Nuxt3 is not as straight forward as you would hope :S